# How to see why single candidates are obviously correct?

Tags: sudoku

I am trying to understand something that should be simple. I have a "easy" puzzle here, and immediately found where 8 should be in the middle box.

[image]

But in various Sudoku Apps, they show "candidates" to the user. And sometimes there is only one candidate available, essentially giving away an answer for free.

It says that 6 and 7 MUST be in those boxes, but I can't see why, it is not obvious at all to me.

Ideally I would rather disable 'candidates' and find such candidates myself. What strategy can be used to show, just by glancing, that 6 and 7 are the only possibilities in those boxes?

Comment: It is more obvious to me that the 4th cell down on the left must be a 7. I see from the Beastly answer that I overlooked the even more obvious.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think the point here is not that the sudoku couldn't be solved (there's lots of numbers that can be easily placed) but why a naked single works and how to spot one

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil it perhaps depends on the sequence in which one applies the various techniques.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A naked single occurs when

> all the possible candidates in a cell are listed, and there is only one value.

Basically, there will be numbers that rule out 8 of 9 possibilities. So for the 7 bottom right:

> [image]

As all the others are ruled out in various ways, it *must* be a 7.

The strategy would be to look at a cell and go through 1-9 and see what is ruled out. If all but one number is ruled out, it must be that number!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that explains it! I'll try to solve squares using this method

Comment: to put it another way, sometimes you know a 7 goes there because of where the other 7s are, but sometimes you know a 7 goes there because of where all the not-7s are.